# Stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I am plotting stacked bar graph of my large data set, it is work fine. But in my plot there is one extra bar is produced as named 'NA'. I don't know what is wrong so please help me. And i also want to change the color of bars and want to make it more visualizing. Is there any way to change the spectral color pattern like the law value's color are more light than dark.I want the color pattern as "white to dark blue" or any dark shade. My dataset,code and plot are as below:

```
Degree  No.of.vertices  Articulationpoint
1   2392    0
2   1439    140
3   981 104
4   698 88
5   579 73
6   445 77
7   366 74
8   272 55
9   255 39
10  226 49
11  179 46
12  146 32
13  121 30
14  124 34 
15  95  25
16  88  28
17  96  39
18  70  17
19  81  34
20  64  20
21  59  22
22  45  20
23  41  19
24  38  17
25  28  14
26  30  18
27  29  16
28  28  13
29  22  9
30  18  11
31  16  6
32  15  9
33  17  11
34  14  5
35  25  11
36  14  6
37  8   7
38  19  10
39  9   3
40  14  6
41  9   2
42  9   4
43  10  6
44  7   5
45  8   4
46  3   2
47  5   4
48  10  8
49  8   4
50  3   1
51  5   5
52  5   5
53  8   6
54  4   2
55  3   3
56  3   2
57  6   5
58  2   2
59  6   4
60  2   2
61  5   4
62  5   2
63  3   3
64  5   4
65  1   0
66  3   2
67  3   2
68  1   1
69  2   0
70  6   6
71  2   0
72  4   4
73  5   5
74  7   6
75  1   1
76  1   1
77  2   2
79  1   1
81  1   0
82  1   1
83  2   2
84  4   2
85  2   2
86  1   0
87  1   1
88  2   2
89  2   2
90  2   2
91  1   1
92  1   1
96  3   3
97  1   1
100 1   1
101 2   1
102 2   2
103 1   1
104 1   0
106 1   1
108 2   1
109 1   1
110 1   1
112 1   1
113 2   2
115 2   1
116 1   1
117 2   2
119 1   1
122 1   0
124 1   1
127 2   1
128 1   1
130 1   1
134 2   2
144 1   1
145 1   1
147 1   1
150 1   1
151 1   1
152 2   2
154 1   1
160 1   0
161 1   1
165 1   1
168 1   1
172 1   1
180 1   1
188 1   1
193 1   1
198 1   1
207 1   1
209 1   1
246 1   1
269 1   1
```

My code is:

```
 d <- read.csv("Data.csv");d
 df <- data.frame(d);df
 df$Degree <- cut(df$Degree,c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,50,75,100,134))
 library(reshape2)
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df, aes(x = Degree, y = No.of.vertices, fill = Articulationpoint)) + 
 geom_bar( stat = "identity", position = "stack", colour = "black" )
```

Which results in:
[image]

In my graph i want white background not that grey boxes. And i also want to fit the graph in 4*4 frame so please help me.

pls help me
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your data preparation you are creating missing values, which are being displayed on the plot:

```
library(dplyr)
# while cutting you are creating missing values
cut(df$Degree,c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,50,75,100,134)) %>% tail(., 30)
#>  [1] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134]
#>  [8] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>     
#> [15] <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>     
#> [22] <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>     
#> [29] <NA>      <NA>     
#> 15 Levels: (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6] (6,7] (7,8] ... (100,134]
```

You could extend your intervals to include all the data, in case that is meaningful:

```
cut(df$Degree,c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,50,75,100,134, 270)) %>% tail(., 30)
#>  [1] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134]
#>  [8] (100,134] (100,134] (100,134] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270]
#> [15] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270]
#> [22] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270] (134,270]
#> [29] (134,270] (134,270]
#> 16 Levels: (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6] (6,7] (7,8] ... (134,270]
```

Alternatively, remove missing values before plotting:

```
df$Degree <- cut(df$Degree,c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,50,75,100,134))
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

---

Changing the background can be done with `theme_bw`, specifying different colors for the gradient by `scale_fill_gradient`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Degree, y = No.of.vertices, fill = Articulationpoint)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", colour = "black" ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "#ecf6fe", low = "#085695") + # change low and hig colours as you whish
  theme_bw() # white background
```

[image]

---

Like lawyeR already mentioned, you can use `ggsave` to control the aspect ratio of your plot when you save it:

```
ggsave("myplot.png", name_of_plot, width = 4, height = 4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much lawyeR and Thomas K.

Answer (score 1):

Using your data and `df <- read.table(textConnection("your data")` I did some cleanup (might have used other arguments to read.table, instead).

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("Degree", "No.of.vertices", "Articulationpoint")
df$Degree <- as.numeric(df$Degree)
df$No.of.vertices <- as.numeric(df$No.of.vertices)

df$Degree <- cut(df$Degree,c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,50,75,100,134))
```

Then ran your plot code but added `theme_bw()`:

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Degree, y = No.of.vertices, fill = Articulationpoint)) + 
  geom_bar( stat = "identity", position = "stack", colour = "black" ) +
  theme_bw()

This removes the grey background but leaves a massive legend.  I am not sure why your outcome differs from mine.

[image: reproduced plot, sort of]

You can set your size dimensions as follows:

```
ggsave(p, filename = "your plot name.png", width = 4, height = 4, unit = "in")
```